# WIX Hooks Built-in search results

Tags: search, velo

[image: Search Results]

I'm having this issue where search results show "FEMALE WINEMAKER" for all results in the database, whether it is true or not. I don't know where it's getting this information. I do have a field labeled "Female Winemaker" but it is not all caps and no value is assigned.

This is a the basic WIX search, I did not adjust any code and I don't know how to filter the display.

Any ideas on how to display what I want in the search results? Ideally it would just be the description of the item/producer.

If I drill down in "inspect" it has the tag  with Female Winemaker listed but I don't know what MARK is.
[image: MARK?]